# Unit test coverage mapping with Webpack and Angular broken?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, karma-coverage, karma-webpack

After spending hours to fix this issue - maybe somebody have an idea, why my coverage reports doesn't map correctly

[image]

I am using:

- Angular 6
- webpack 4
- karma 3.0
- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter 2.0.4

If you guys have some ideas, i will post further config files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was simple. I got a hint if something like this happens, the reason is often, that the sourcemap files are not correct.

I run:

```
ng test --source-map=true
```

and it works!